# Best way to show architecture of a specified file system?

Tags: linux, debian, bash

Admitting a filesystem is installed in ~/FS/ (which is its root), how can I check its architecture without chroot?

I tried with `dpkg --root=~/FS/ --print-architecture` but it still prints me the architecture of my root filesystem ("/").

I've read man-pages of `dpkg-architecture`, but there is no way to specify a path to a root filesystem.

**I need something generic, because I need it for a bash script and not only for one filesystem.**

An unclean alternative for me is to use:

```
dpkg --root=~/FS/ -l | grep [[:space:]]passwd[[:space:]]
```

and then check for its architecture, because I know that (at the moment) the `passwd` package is installed on all the filesystems I have to check.

Any better proposition(s)?

**Also note** that I tried with `dpkg` for its simplicity, I don't imperatively need a dpkg command, but I need something fast.

Kind regards :-)

Comment: Almost all Linux installations should have something in `/etc/*-release`.  Depending on the information included by the OS architecture may be included in there, it is on openSUSE.

Comment: What do you mean by "architecture of a file-system" ? The actual file system used (which can typically be displayed with `stat --file-system --format=%T /path/` ) or  what hardware (CPU/32-/64-bit) architecture the default kernel (and/or binaries) on that file system  is intended for?

Comment: @Matt on Debian, I only have /etc/os-release file which don't show me the architecture

Comment: @HBruijn I have many products with different CPU architectures (amd64, armel, ...).  It will be too long to explain why I need it. What I need is: I have a untar-ed root filesystems (e.g. in ~/FS/) and I need to know which architecture (amd64, armel, ...) my filesystem's have by specifying a path to its root

Comment: Do your file system images have the kernel images a consistent location, such as /boot/? Because a simple `file boot/* |grep kernel`  might identify enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can try to use `readelf` in this way

```
readelf -a /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.18-308.el5  | egrep "(Class:|Machine:)"
Class:                             ELF64
Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
```

For 32 bit binary

```
readelf -a test  | egrep "(Class:|Machine:)"
  Class:                             ELF32
```

so using `readelf` you can query the arch in you path
      Machine:                           Intel 80386